# Transforming multiple data frame columns into one series

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, for-loop

I have a dataset df(250,3) 250 raws and three columns. I want to write a loop that merges the content of each column in my dataframe to have one single series(250,1) of 250 raws and 1 columns 'df_single'. The manual operation is the following:

df_single = df['colour']+" "+df['model']+" "+df['size']

How can I create df_single with a for loop, or non-manually?

I tried to write this code with TypeError

```
df_conc=[]
for var in cols:
    cat_list=df_code_part[var]
    df_conc = df_conc+" "+cat_list
```

TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Comment: Do you want the sum?

Comment: @Annalix you can use `df.itertuples()` or `df.iterrows()`.

Comment: I dont think he needs a loop

Comment: there is some issue with answers - do you need `concatenate` all columns of `DataFrame` or only some columns specified in list?

Comment: I need to sum as in df_single = df['colour']+" "+df['model']+" "+df['size'] but  a general way and with space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if need join 3 columns then your solution is really good:

```
df_single = df['colour']+" "+df['model']+" "+df['size']
```

If need general solution for many columns use [`DataFrame.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) for convert to strings if necessary with [`DataFrame.add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) for add whitespace, `sum` for concatenate and last remove tralining whitespeces by [`Series.str.rstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html) for remove traling whitespace:

```
cols = ['color','model','size']
df_single = df[cols].astype(str).add(' ').sum(axis=1).str.rstrip()
```

Or:

```
df_single = df[cols].astype(str).apply(' '.join, axis=1)
```

Comment: Your solution is also incorrect, it is intuited that he wants not to have to write the name of the columns and that is why he wants to use a loop. He didn't know what sum could use (axis = 1)

Comment: are you sure cols are not all columns?

Comment: "use in code for var in cols: - so you are wrong".?

Answer (score 1):

if you want the sum  You need use:

```
df_single=df.astype(str).add(' ').sum(axis=1).str.rstrip()
```

**if you don't want to add all the columns then you need to select them previously:**

```
columns=['colour','model','size']
df_single=df[columns].astype(str).add(' ').sum(axis=1).str.rstrip()
```

Comment: In this case i need to add all columns. But my questions was most referred to how to generalise the manual +" "+ . I see it is with apply(' '.join, axis=1) or add(' ').sum(axis=1).str.rstrip(). Thanks!

Comment: @Annalix - Added to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have spaces between columns, run:

```
df.apply(' '.join, axis=1)
```

"Ordinary" *df.sum(axis=1)* concatenates all columns, but **without**
spaces between them.